# jquery scrolling is not recognize in a page with youtube iframe

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a script in jquery that will identify section numbering using scroll event in jquery but the moment I added youtube iframe on the page this scroll event won't fire any result. Is there anyway I can fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    nextSection = 1;
    $('.pre-num').html(nextSection);
    console.log('still firing');
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $section2.offset().top) {
    nextSection = 2;
    $('.pre-num').html(nextSection);
    console.log('wont fire');
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $section3.offset().top) {
    nextSection = 3;
    $('.pre-num').html(nextSection);
    console.log('wont fire');
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 3000) {
    nextSection = 4;
    $('.pre-num').html(nextSection);
    console.log('wont fire');
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mind mentioning/adding what jQuery code you are using? What errors/warning your browser JS console show?

Comment: I used scrollify.js to cause every section in the page to snap everytime a user will scroll down or up. And I added a condition in a preloader if they want to have a youtube frame as a hero at the top then they can click the sound on or sound off for mute else cancel for no youtube iframe in the hero area. Everything works fine in the image hero area but if they choose where the iframe is visible then the scroll event wont work. I did check the console and there is no warning.

Comment: $(window).on('scroll', function(){
 if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
 nextSection = 1;
 $('.pre-num').html(nextSection);    
 console.log('still firing');
 }
 if($(window).scrollTop() == $section2.offset().top) {
 nextSection = 2;
 $('.pre-num').html(nextSection);  
 console.log('wont fire');
 }
 if($(window).scrollTop() == $section3.offset().top) {
 nextSection = 3;
 $('.pre-num').html(nextSection); 
 console.log('wont fire');
 }
 if($(window).scrollTop() > 3000) {
 nextSection = 4;
 $('.pre-num').html(nextSection);  
 console.log('wont fire');
 }         
 });

Answer (score 0):

I see now the problem. When the youtube iframe is present the scroll event is working but not the `offset().top` so I just change the value to real number of the offset value so instead of using  `== $section2.offset().top` I just replace it with `== 1213` just like the first if condition.

Thanks @Junaid for your time to make comment on my question.